# javaFX: MediaPlayer stops playing while STATUS is PLAYING

Tags: java, javafx

I have 8 mediaplayer, that play videos at the same time and have the same controls: there is 1 Play/Pause Button, 1 Stop Button, 1 Slider for the time and 1 Slider for volume.

My Program is extremely buggy when I seek on the Time-Slider, the videos often stop playing, without the `STATUS`of the player changing from `PLAYING`.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, this is my first JavaFX project.

In constructor:

```
    timeSlider.setOnMouseReleased(event -> {
        timeSlider.setValueChanging(true);
        timeSlider.setValue((event.getX() / timeSlider.getWidth()) * timeSlider.getMax());
        timeSlider.setValueChanging(false);
        forceSeekMediaPlayer(timeSlider.getValue());
    });

    controlMediaPlayer = mpList.get(1);                           // just the second player
    controlMediaPlayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener(observable -> {
        updateValues(controlMediaPlayer);
        if (!mediaPlayerCloseToMediaPlayerOne(mpList, Main.MAX_MILLI_SECS_DIFFERENCE_VIDEOS)) {
            forceSeekMediaPlayer(controlMediaPlayer.getCurrentTime().toMillis());
        }
    });

    controlMediaPlayer.statusProperty().addListener(observable -> {
        System.out.println(controlMediaPlayer.getStatus());
        if (controlMediaPlayer.getStatus() == Status.PLAYING) {
            playButton.setGraphic(pauseImageView);
        } else {
            playButton.setGraphic(playImageView);
        }
    });

    timeSlider.setOnMousePressed(event -> timeSlider.setValueChanging(true));
```

Other methods:

```
private void forceSeekMediaPlayer(double to) {
    final Duration seekTo = Duration.millis(to);
    for (MediaPlayer mp : mpList) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            mp.seek(seekTo);
        }).start();
    }
}

protected void updateValues(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if (playTime != null && timeSlider != null) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Duration currentTime = mp.getCurrentTime();
                playTime.setText(formatTime(currentTime, duration));
                timeSlider.setDisable(duration.isUnknown());
                if (!timeSlider.isDisabled() && duration.greaterThan(Duration.ZERO) && !timeSlider.isValueChanging()) {
                    timeSlider.setValue(currentTime.toMillis());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The program has trouble when the videos wrap at the end too.

Comment: Why are you creating and starting a new `Thread` each time you want to seek to a new time (made worse by creating and starting a new `Thread` for **each** `MediaPlayer`)? I would not be surprised if that resulted in dozens of threads being created (and quickly dying).

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: @Slaw I had freezing videos (also being stuck on PLAYING, pretty much like now, but all the time). Another SO post said to seek only on not GUI thread and that helped a lot.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. The media API is designed to be interacted with on the FX thread. Can you create and provide a [mre]?

Comment: don't repost a question - closing this as duplicate, the other has the [mcve] as suggested